# "wouldn't have done" vs "couldn't have done" + if not vs unless

Tags: subjunctives

I have run across a MCQ for which I chose the wrong answer. It's from a Chinese Entrance Exam grammar problem set. Here is the question:

> I couldn't have got to the meeting on time ______ an earlier train.
>   A. if I had not caught
>   B. unless I had caught
>   C. if I didn't catch
>   D. unless I caught

The correct answer given in the key section is B, but I think A makes sense as well. I know that A would be 100% correct if the independent clause were *I wouldn't have got* instead of *I couldn't have got*, but I think in this case maybe *couldn't have done* can have the same meaning?

For example, I think I have heard of the expression 'I couldn't have done it without you', which I suppose has the same meaning as 'I wouldn't have been able to do it without you', meaning it would have been not possible for me to do it had it not been for you. In this case *couldn't have done* refers to something that had happened. By the same logic, I think A should also be right.